# MySQL Query for finding a "LAST" row, based on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table to log the registration status changes of pupils:

```
CREATE TABLE `pupil_registration_statuses` (
`status_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status_pupil_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`status_status_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`status_effectivedate` DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`),
INDEX `status_pupil_id` (`status_pupil_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Example data:

```
INSERT INTO `pupil_registration_statuses` (`status_id`, `status_pupil_id`, `status_status_id`, `status_effectivedate`) VALUES
    (1, 123, 1, '2013-05-06'),
    (2, 123, 2, '2014-03-15'),
    (3, 123, 5, '2013-03-15'),
    (4, 123, 6, '2013-05-06'),
    (5, 234, 2, '2013-02-02'),
    (6, 234, 4, '2013-04-17'),
    (7, 345, 2, '2014-02-01'),
    (8, 345, 3, '2013-06-01');
```

It is possible that statuses can be inserted, thus the sequence of dates does not necessarily follow the same sequence of IDs.

For example: `status_id` 1 might has a date of 2013-05-06, but `status_id` 3 might have a date of 2013-03-15.

`status_id` values are, however, sequential within any particular date. Thus if a pupil's registration status changes multiple times on one day then the last row will will reflect their status for that date.

It is necessary to find out a particular student's registration status on a particular date. The following query works for an individual pupil:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pupil_registration_statuses 
WHERE status_pupil_id = 123
    AND status_effectivedate <= '2013-05-06'
ORDER BY status_effectivedate DESC, status_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This returns the expected row of `status_id = 4`

However, I now need to issue a (single) query to return the status for all pupils on a particular date.

The following query is proposed, but doesn't obey the "last `status_id` in a day" requirement:

```
SELECT *
FROM pupil_registration_statuses prs
    INNER JOIN (SELECT status_pupil_id, MAX(status_effectivedate) last_date
        FROM pupil_registration_statuses
        WHERE status_effectivedate <= '2013-05-06'
        GROUP BY status_pupil_id) qprs ON prs.status_pupil_id = qprs.status_pupil_id AND prs.status_effectivedate = qprs.last_date;
```

This query, however, returns 2 rows for pupil 123.

**EDIT**

To clarify, if the input is the date `'2013-05-06'`, I expect to get the rows 4 and 6 from the query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68ee6/2

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand what you mean. Are you referring to the `<= [date]`? That is needed because not every pupil will have an entry for every date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM pupil_registration_statuses a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT prs.status_pupil_id
            , MIN(prs.status_id) min_status_id
         FROM pupil_registration_statuses prs
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT status_pupil_id
                   , MAX(status_effectivedate) last_date
                FROM pupil_registration_statuses
               WHERE status_effectivedate <= '2013-05-06'
               GROUP
                  BY status_pupil_id
            ) qprs 
           ON prs.status_pupil_id = qprs.status_pupil_id 
          AND prs.status_effectivedate = qprs.last_date
        GROUP
           BY prs.status_pupil_id
     ) b
    ON b.min_status_id = a.status_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68ee6/7

(Incidentally, there's an ugly and undocumented hack for this kind of problem which goes something like this:

```
SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT * FROM prs WHERE status_effectivedate <= '2013-05-06' ORDER BY status_pupil_id, status_effectivedate DESC, status_id)x GROUP BY status_pupil_id;
```

...but I didn't tell you that! ;) )

Comment: This is great - just one modification to get the last `status_id` would be to change the `MIN(prs.status_id)` to `MAX(prs.status_id)`. Then it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Just a side note - subqueries, while powerful, are normally not as good in performance as an equivalent without subqueries. So my advice here is: go ahead and use them if there is no other way to make it work.

Comment: (that's complete nonsense)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed where clause, please try it.

```
SELECT *
    FROM pupil_registration_statuses prs
        INNER JOIN (SELECT status_pupil_id, MAX(status_effectivedate) last_date
            FROM pupil_registration_statuses
            WHERE Datediff(status_effectivedate, '2013-05-06') <= 0
            GROUP BY status_pupil_id) qprs ON prs.status_pupil_id = qprs.status_pupil_id AND prs.status_effectivedate = qprs.last_date;
```

EDIT

Try this

```
SELECT *
    FROM 

        (
            select status_pupil_id,max(status_id) as status_id from pupil_registration_statuses innr
            --where Datediff(dd,status_effectivedate, '2013-05-06') >= 0
            group by status_pupil_id

        )as ca 
        inner join pupil_registration_statuses prs on prs.status_id = ca.status_id
where   Datediff(dd,prs.status_effectivedate, '2013-05-06') >= 0
```

Comment: This returns only the exact opposite of what my query requires. Changing the `>= 0` to `<= 0` simply reproduces my results.

Comment: Oh!that means I missed on symbol.

Comment: I've edited above to what I tried, but to clarify: it produces an equivalent data set.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to...

1) Get 1 row per person.

2) Get the status changes from the specific day you manually input.

3) Get the last status changes from within the specific day.

If that's right, you need the query you already have ordering by date and then by id, just with a [distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

```
SELECT DISTINCT on status_pupil_id *
FROM pupil_registration_statuses 
WHERE status_pupil_id = 123
    AND status_effectivedate <= '2013-05-06'
ORDER BY status_effectivedate DESC, status_id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the last status that was entered. So, for example, on 2013-05-06, pupil 234 has status 4 (which took effect on 2013-04-17). That should also be part of the returned data.

Comment: Did you try changing the status_effectivedate to before 2013-04-17? That query filters by the date and then makes the distinct, so use an effectivedate in which all pupils have at least one status.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, though. I need to see the last status that was entered for a particular pupil.